# jupyter-notebook modify config_path to remove system wide paths

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to setup jupyter notebook on an Ubuntu server using an SSH tunnel.

My server restricts access to the root directory. I can setup the tunnel, but when I go to the http a permission error is generated.

It seems that Jupyter even listing the content of a root directory is prohibited on this server. Therefore, I'm trying to change the config-path to remove system paths.

```
(jupyter) an25562@ochmcomp01:~$ jupyter --path

config:
  /stor/home/an25562/.jupyter
  /stor/home/an25562/miniconda3/envs/jupyter/etc/jupyter
  /usr/local/etc/jupyter
  /etc/jupyter
data:
  /stor/home/an25562/.local/share/jupyter
  /stor/home/an25562/miniconda3/envs/jupyter/share/jupyter
  /usr/local/share/jupyter
  /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
  /stor/home/an25562/.local/share/jupyter/runtime
```

**How can I alter the config path to remove root directorie**s, ie.:

```
/usr/local/etc/jupyter, 
/etc/jupyter,
/usr/local/share/jupyter, 
/usr/share/jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

The permission issue is most likely not due to these folders since most of these are fall back folders. You can run the server in debug mode (pass --debug command-line parameter when starting the server) and check server logs for any clues.

If you still think its the folder configs that need to be changed, refer https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html